# Need more simple JS code with only one ID attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Example below **using some name id** = **btnHour1**, **btnHour2** etc .. that made me be lengthy code. 
I've been looking for a tutorial like this but it was not found.

HTML:

```
<div id="lblHour"></div>
<div>
<button id="btnHour1" value="03:00 PM">Available 1</button>
<button id="btnHour2" value="03:30 PM">Available 2</button>
<button id="btnHour3" value="04:00 PM">Available 3</button>
<button id="btnHour4" value="04:30 PM">Available 4</button>
<button id="btnHour5" value="05:00 PM">Available 5</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#btnHour1").click(function(){    
    var getValue = $("#btnHour1").val();
    document.getElementById("lblHour").innerHTML = getValue;
});
$("#btnHour2").click(function(){
    var getValue = $("#btnHour2").val();
    document.getElementById("lblHour").innerHTML = getValue;
});
$("#btnHour3").click(function(){
    var getValue = $("#btnHour3").val();
    document.getElementById("lblHour").innerHTML = getValue;
});
$("#btnHour4").click(function(){
    var getValue = $("#btnHour4").val();
    document.getElementById("lblHour").innerHTML = getValue;
});
$("#btnHour5").click(function(){
    var getValue = $("#btnHour5").val();
    document.getElementById("lblHour").innerHTML = getValue;
});
```

});

I need advice to make my **JavaScript** code more simple and short by using **only one name** **id** = **"btnHour"**.

Execute code:
https://jsfiddle.net/L5m8xop4/

Comment: I don't need a class in this code, after all, this problem has been solved by Darren Davies .. @a-wolff , **thanks for the comments**.

Comment: You don't need but this would be better regarding code maintenance. But ya, using `startsWith` attribute selector is simple enough. The question could be, do you really need to set for each `button` an ID?!...

Comment: I'll make a lot of button so I think it would be better using the ID attribute to define each button. if there are any other suggestions please let me know. @a-wolff , please can you give an example, maybe I can use if I've made this code related to my mysql database.

Comment: Example using class: https://jsfiddle.net/L5m8xop4/1/  Now it really depends your use case.

Comment: I tried, it looks like you're right, this code is more simple and short, so I more easily to connect this code with other code.  **"thanks for the advice"**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`Starts with`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector (^=):

```
$("button[id^='btnHour'").on("click", function() {
    var getValue = $(this).val();
    document.getElementById("lblHour").innerHTML = getValue;
});
```

Full example:

```js
$("button[id^='btnHour'").on("click", function() {
    var getValue = $(this).val();
    document.getElementById("lblHour").innerHTML = getValue;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="lblHour"></div>
<div>
<button id="btnHour1" value="03:00 PM">Available 1</button>
<button id="btnHour2" value="03:30 PM">Available 2</button>
<button id="btnHour3" value="04:00 PM">Available 3</button>
<button id="btnHour4" value="04:30 PM">Available 4</button>
<button id="btnHour5" value="05:00 PM">Available 5</button>
```